# How to count in binary in base 10

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary, decimal

I would like an integer in c++ to count up in binary like:
1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111
But i want to values to be in base 10 like:
one, ten, eleven, one hundred, one hundred and one, etc.
Basically count up in decimal but look like base 10.
Is there a algorithm to do this.

-Joseph

Comment: [Solution is 111111111000](https://ideone.com/pS9Gpz). even if `0` would be even lower.

Comment: No programming is required. *x* is divisible by 72, iff it is divisible by both 8 and 9. A number (written in decimal) is divisible by 8 iff its last 3 digits are divsible by 8. It is divisible by 9 iff the sum of its digits is divisible by 9. The only 3-digit number with only the digits 0 and 1 which is divisible by 0 is 000.  The sum of the digits of a number written with only 0 and 1 is the number of 1s. So if 0 is excluded, the smallest such number divisible by 72 has nine 1s followed by three zeros: 111111111000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should proceed:

- use a string for binary values to display it
- you should implement a cycle which will end when your number reaches 0 and should write the result of currentValue % 2 to the start of your string then divide your number with 2
- you should implement a function which will return the humanely readable number text, you might want to take inspiration from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30525/convert-number-to-words), but a clue is that the digit number % 3 is relevant. If it is 0, then you will need to write the digit if the digit next to it to the left does not happen to be one, so values between 11-19 are an exception here and don't forget thousand, million, billion, if the modulo is 1, then you will have a special text, like eleven, ... nineteen, twenty, ..., ninety and if modulo is 2, then the text will be the digit + "hundred"

You will basically have a number and will be able to get the binary from it and the textual representation as well.

String is not necessary for the algorithm, one can cout a `std::bitset` as well.